# How to reference a subproject dir from a root gradle task when calling task from subproject

Tags: gradle

I have a root project gradle task defined below. I am

```
task createVersionTxtResourceFile {
    doLast {
        def webAppVersionFile = new File("$projectDir/src/main/resources/VERSION.txt")
        def appVersion = project.ext.$full_version

        println "writing VERSION.txt to " + webAppVersionFile + ", containing " + appVersion
        webAppVersionFile.delete()
        webAppVersionFile.write(appVersion)
    }
}
```

In a few subprojects, I want to run this task and create the `VERSION.txt` file in the subproject's `src/main/resources/VERSION.txt`. My problem is that the root level task's `$projectDir` is the root project.

Is it possible to define a root level task that uses the sub-project directory when invoking it? Or perhaps there's a better approach all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it slightly more controlled when you register an action to wait for the `java` plugin to be applied on the subproject. With this you can create the task only in subprojects who contain the desired `compileJava` task and configure everything from the `root` project.

```
subprojects { sub ->
    //register an action which gets executed when the java plugins gets applied.
    //if the project is already configured with the java plugin
    //then this action gets executed right away.
    sub.plugins.withId("java") {
      //create the task and save it.
      def createVersionTxtResourceFile = sub.tasks.create("createVersionTxtResourceFile") {
          doLast {
              def webAppVersionFile = new File("${sub.projectDir}/src/main/resources/VERSION.txt")
              def appVersion = rootProject.full_version

              println "writing VERSION.txt to " + webAppVersionFile + ", containing " + appVersion
              webAppVersionFile.delete()
              webAppVersionFile.write(appVersion)
          }
      }
      // set the task dependency
      sub.tasks.compileJava.dependsOn createVersionTxtResourceFile
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point. I did something similar to that to add to the "test" task, but only for projects with type Test. I could probably do something similar to that for android-specific modules as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just defining the task in each subproject, and setting a dependency on it in the appropriate subprojects:

```
subprojects {

    task createVersionTxtResourceFile {
        doLast {
            def webAppVersionFile = new File("$projectDir/src/main/resources/VERSION.txt")
            def appVersion = rootProject.full_version

            println "writing VERSION.txt to " + webAppVersionFile + ", containing " + appVersion
            webAppVersionFile.delete()
            webAppVersionFile.write(appVersion)
        }
    }
}
```

then in a subproject `build.gradle`:

`compileJava.dependsOn createVersionTxtResourceFile`